# JS библиотека для создания туториалсов на сайте

Tags: javascript

Иногда на сайтах делают интерактивный туториалс по его интерфейсу и о том, как пользоваться его функционалом. Кто какие JS библиотеки знает для этого? 
Речь идет приблизительно о таком:
[image]

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Answer (score 3):

Использовал один, очень похож на гифку в вопросе.
http://bootstraptour.com/

Answer (score 0):

Еще такой есть [Bootstro.js](http://clu3.github.io/bootstro.js/) тоже бутстраповский. И [Intro.js](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/)
 можно посмотреть.